# Trying to execute a assembler bytestream as a C native function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, return, memory-address

I was trying to overwrite the return address of main() with the address of the shellcode that I wrote in assembly.

My assembly program :

ExitShell.asm

```
SECTION .text
global _start

_start:

    jmp short shellOffset
    
    Shellcode:

        pop esi
        lea ecx, [esi]
        mov dl, 12
        mov bl, 1
        mov al, 4
        int 0x80
        mov bl, 20
        mov al, 1
        int 0x80    


    shellOffset:

        call Shellcode
        msg db "Hello World",0xa
```

My .c file in which I am overwriting the return address :

ShellCode.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

char shellcode[] = "\xeb\x11\x5e\x8d\x0e\xb2\x0c\xb3\x01\xb0\x04\xcd\x80"\
           "\xb3\x14\xb0\x01\xcd\x80\xe8\xea\xff\xff\xff"\
               "\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x57\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x0a";

    void main()
    {
    
        int *ret;
        ret = (int *)&ret + 2;
        (*ret) = (int)shellcode;
    
    
    }
```

I compiled the program with the following command :

```
gcc -O0 -o sh ShellCode.c -fno-stack-protector -zexec -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -g
```

When I executed the program, I received the segmentation fault error. Loading the program into gdb, I found that it was giving the error at ret statement in assembly

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x080483b4 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x080483b5 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x080483b7 <+3>: sub    $0x10,%esp
   0x080483ba <+6>: lea    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
   0x080483bd <+9>: add    $0x8,%eax
   0x080483c0 <+12>:    mov    %eax,-0x4(%ebp)
   0x080483c3 <+15>:    mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
   0x080483c6 <+18>:    mov    $0x804a040,%edx
   0x080483cb <+23>:    mov    %edx,(%eax)
   0x080483cd <+25>:    leave  
=> 0x080483ce <+26>:    ret
```

What is the issue? I am new to this.

Comment: What could you possible be trying to accomplish? Why are you not embedding an `asm` directive in the C code instead of assembling the code and turning into a C string? In this instance, the compiler has much more understanding of calling conventions and all code generation than you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can have many reasons. You disabled the stack smashing detector, but that doesn't mean, that `ret` in main is going to be allocated right after the return address. The compiler and linker have some leeway in aligning the variables' addresses to improve performance or to satisfy CPU alignment requirements.

Another issue is, that `shellcode` will be placed in the `.data` segment, which may be set nonexecutable, so main returning to shellcode would trigger that trap.

Comment: thanks for pointing out that .. :) I forgot to add stack word in the compile statement . It should have been  .. gcc -o sh ShellCode.c -fno-stack-protector -z execstack